# 3 links animate on hover but 1 does not

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

The `<b><a class="external" href="http://tuleburgpress.com/">Tuleburg Press</a></b>` link is not animating on hover. All of the other links animate on hover. The link that's not working is line breaking on the page, is that why? Any ideas?

```css
a.external {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
 line-height: 3rem;
 font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
 color: #ff9f43;
}

a.external:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff9f43;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a.external:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  color: #ff9f43;
  background-color: #ff9f43;
}
```

```html
<h2>Brought to you by <b><a class="external" href="http://placeholdermag.com/">Placeholder Magazine</b></a>, the <b><a class="external" href="http://www.arts.ca.gov/">California Arts Council</a></b> and the <b><a class="external" href="http://www.stocktonca.gov/government/boardCom/sArts.html">Stockton Arts Commission</a></b>, <b><a class="external" href="http://tuleburgpress.com/">Tuleburg Press</a></b>, and are proud to announce Stockton's first Zine making workshop series for kids.</h2>
```

Comment: Yes, that line break appears to be why it's breaking. In SO's code debugger, `STOCKTON ARTS COMMISSION` now has a line break and doesn't animate, while `TULEBURG PRESS` doesn't have a line break, and does animate.

Comment: I think it is because of line wrapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `<b>` is deprecated, and if you are using `font-weight:700` you don't need it nor `strong`, so remove it (because besides this reason you are closing tags incorrectly)

The problem is that the `a` is an inline element therefore you need to set `a` as block level element for example using `inline-block`

```css
a.external {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  color: #ff9f43;
  display: inline-block
}

a.external:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff9f43;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a.external:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  color: #ff9f43;
  background-color: #ff9f43;
}
```

```html
<h2>Brought to you by <a class="external" href="http://placeholdermag.com/">Placeholder Magazine</a>, the <a class="external" href="http://www.arts.ca.gov/">California Arts Council</a> and the <a class="external" href="http://www.stocktonca.gov/government/boardCom/sArts.html">Stockton Arts Commission</a>,
  <a class="external" href="http://tuleburgpress.com/">Tuleburg Press</a>, and are proud to announce Stockton's first Zine making workshop series for kids.</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the line getting wrapped and broken.

Add `display: inline-block` to make sure it is on the same line. Don't use `<b>` tag instead use `<strong>` or `<span>` with `font-weight: bold`.

```css
a.external {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  color: #ff9f43;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.external:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff9f43;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a.external:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  color: #ff9f43;
  background-color: #ff9f43;
}
```

```html
<h2>Brought to you by <b><a class="external" href="http://placeholdermag.com/">Placeholder Magazine</a></b>, the <b><a class="external" href="http://www.arts.ca.gov/">California Arts Council</a></b> and the <b><a class="external" href="http://www.stocktonca.gov/government/boardCom/sArts.html">Stockton Arts Commission</a></b>,
  <b><a class="external" href="http://tuleburgpress.com/">Tuleburg Press</a></b>, and are proud to announce Stockton's first Zine making workshop series for kids.</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation is not happening because of the line break. But more than that, you are closing the first set of tags wrongly. If you take a closer look at the first link of your code, it's clearer :

```
Brought to you by
<b>
  <a class="external" href="http://placeholdermag.com/">
    Placeholder Magazine
  </b>
</a>
```

You're doing `<b><a></b></a>` instead of `<b><a></a></b>`. As ou opened the `a` tag last, you'll need to close it first, and only then close the encapsulating `b` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative if you want to keep your elements **inline**:

```css
a.external {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  color: #ff9f43;
  background:linear-gradient(#ff9f43,#ff9f43) bottom/0% 3px no-repeat;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
a.external:hover {
  background-size:100% 3px; 
}
```

```html
<h2>Brought to you by <a class="external" href="http://placeholdermag.com/">Placeholder Magazine</a>, the <a class="external" href="http://www.arts.ca.gov/">California Arts Council</a> and the <a class="external" href="http://www.stocktonca.gov/government/boardCom/sArts.html">Stockton Arts Commission</a>,
  <a class="external" href="http://tuleburgpress.com/">Tuleburg Press</a>, and are proud to announce Stockton's first Zine making workshop series for kids.</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the order of your first links tags and bold (strong) tags weren't opened and closed in the correct order. Try:

```
<h2>Brought to you by <b><a class="external" href="http://placeholdermag.com/">Placeholder Magazine</a></b>, the <b><a class="external" href="http://www.arts.ca.gov/">California Arts Council</a></b> and the <b><a class="external" href="http://www.stocktonca.gov/government/boardCom/sArts.html">Stockton Arts Commission</a></b>, <b><a class="external" href="http://tuleburgpress.com/">Tuleburg Press</a></b>, and are proud to announce Stockton's first Zine making workshop series for kids.</h2>
```